# Can this network system Work properly?

Tags: wireless-router, routing

I have connected two different LANs with their own ISPs. I have two wireless routers with #1 router lan port connected to lan port of #2 router. Now:-

## 1 router: -

Lan Ip address = 192.168.0.1

Subnet Mask= 255.255.255.0

DHCP=ON
POOL= 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.110

Added static route to 192.168.1.0 via the gateway 192.168.1.1

ISP=WISHNET BROADBAND.

## 2 router: -

Lan Ip address = 192.168.1.1

Subnet Mask= 255.255.255.0

DHCP=ON
POOL= 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.110

Added static route to 192.168.0.0 via the gateway 192.168.0.1

ISP=AIRTEL 4G LTE

WILL THIS SYSTEM WORK WITHOUT ANY PROBLEMS? PLEASE COMMENT I AM TOTALLY CONFUSED  !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/973726/495739 .

Comment: I have only asked that question LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah they'll work independently, but they will never see each other as they are are separate networks, for 0.0 to see 1.0 you need one router to be in both IP networks.